# Access hash params in React ( /callback#token=1234&...etc)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch a Oauth token from an API using password grant. When I get redirected back to the /callback, React is converting/redirecting the ?..query to a #..query:

For example:

http://localhost:3000/callback#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOi...&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=31535999

How do I access these params in my components then? I can see that there is a full value of the hash param string in `props.location.hash` ... should I just slice up the string, or is there a React way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string):

```js
import queryString from 'query-string';

queryString.parse(props.location.hash)

// { access_token: '...', token_type: '...' }
```

there are also similar packages: [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring), [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs).

Answer (score 3):

Esiest way:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash);
let token = params.get('access_token');
```

Comment: The issue with this is you'll end up with the first query not being parsed properly. For this to work, you need to add `.replace('#','')` i.e: `new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''))`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use smth like this function to get object from `props.location.hash`:

```js
const getJsonFromUrl = str => {
  const query = str.substr(1);
  const result = {};

  query.split('&').forEach(function(part) {
    const item = part.split('=');
    result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  });

  return result;
};

const { access_token, token_type } = getJsonFromUrl(props.location.hash);
```